# C++ Allocator::destroy throws

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sfml

EDIT: I have changed the source to use extra struct instead of not so nice tuple.

EDIT: This is solved, while I didnt find out why this is happening, I rebuild the code so that it is not dependant on nesting but on extra variable checks

New found, question at the bottom!

I have a SFML project set up. I have simple class, which is used to handle periodic events.

Class:

```
#ifndef _TIMER_H_
#define _TIMER_H_

#include <SFML/System.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

namespace lg{
    struct TimerData{
        bool periodic;
        std::function<void()> function;
        sf::Clock clock;
        float timeout;
        float runTime;
        bool toRemove;
        bool stopEss;
    };

    class Timer{
        std::vector<TimerData> vec;
    public:
        Timer() : vec() {}
        Timer(const Timer& t) : vec(t.vec) {}
        Timer(Timer&& t) : vec(std::move(t.vec)) {}
        Timer& operator=(const Timer& t)
        {
            vec = t.vec;
            return *this;
        }

        Timer& operator=(Timer&& t)
        {
            vec = std::move(t.vec);
            return *this;
        }

        void onTimeout(float timeMilliseconds, std::function<void()> callback)
        {
            TimerData dat;
            dat.periodic = false;
            dat.timeout = timeMilliseconds;
            dat.function = callback;
            dat.toRemove = false;
            dat.runTime = 0;
            dat.clock = sf::Clock();
            dat.stopEss = false;

            vec.push_back(dat);
        }

        void onPeriod(float timeMilliseconds, std::function<void()> callback)
        {
            TimerData dat;
            dat.periodic = true;
            dat.timeout = timeMilliseconds;
            dat.function = callback;
            dat.toRemove = false;
            dat.runTime = 0;
            dat.clock = sf::Clock();
            dat.stopEss = false;

            vec.push_back(dat);
        }

        void onPeriod(float timeMilliseconds, float initialDelay, std::function<void()> callback)
        {
            onTimeout(initialDelay, [=](){ onPeriod(timeMilliseconds, callback); });
        }

        void onTempPeriod(float timeMilliseconds, float runFor, std::function<void()> callback)
        {
            TimerData dat;
            dat.periodic = true;
            dat.timeout = timeMilliseconds;
            dat.function = callback;
            dat.toRemove = false;
            dat.runTime = runFor;
            dat.clock = sf::Clock();
            dat.stopEss = true;

            vec.push_back(dat);
        }

        void onTempPeriod(float timeMilliseconds, float initialDelay, float runFor,
                            std::function<void()> callback)
        {
            onTimeout(initialDelay, [=](){
                onTempPeriod(timeMilliseconds, runFor, callback);
            });
        }

        void check()
        {
            bool removeOne = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
            {
                auto& a = vec.at(i);

                auto elapsed = a.clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();

                if (elapsed >= a.timeout)
                {
                    a.function();
                    if (a.periodic)
                    {
                        a.clock.restart();

                        a.runTime -= elapsed;
                        if (a.stopEss && a.runTime <= 0.f)
                        {
                            removeOne = true;
                            a.toRemove = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        a.toRemove = true;
                        removeOne = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (removeOne)
            {
                vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                    [](const TimerData& t){
                        return t.toRemove;
                    }),
                    vec.end());
            }
        }
    };
}

#endif    //_TIMER_H_
```

If you try running:

```
std::cout << "testing timer:\n";

lg::Timer t;
t.onTempPeriod(500.f, 5000.f, [](){std::cout << "timeout\n"; });

while(1)
{
    t.check();
}
```

it works fine, the timer prints "timeout\n" every 500 ms for 5 seconds and after that nothing happens.

But if you try to run the second overload of onTempPeriod:

```
t.onTempPeriod(500.f, 1000.f, 3000.f, [](){std::cout << "timeout\n"; });
```

(First argument is every how often should the lambda be called
second argument is how long it should wait before calling it
third argument is for how long it should work)

After the 1 second initial wait time, the program pops "Program.exe has triggered a brakepoint." The error is not even named, and the brakepoint is here: `retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);` which is line 50 of free.c file.

I stepped over the code and the error is called when the `vec.erase(..., vec.end());` is executed. In this special case the whole vector has to be earsed, which is checked in the Visual's implementation. It therefore calls `clear()` on the vector, which calls a few functions and when the program gets into `Allocator::destroy`, which looks like:

```
template<class _Uty>
    void destroy(_Uty *_Ptr)
    {    // destroy object at _Ptr
    _Ptr->~_Uty();
    }
```

when the execution reaches _Ptr->~_Uty(), it just triggers brakepoint.

Any help with this?

To note, this works perfectly fine with all other functions, and it most likely is not because of the nested insertation inside `onTempPeriod`. This is proven by working `onPeriod` which calls `onTimeout`.

Edited part: It really is something going on with combination. No matter if it is inside the function or inside main, this code will always trigger the error.

```
t.onTimeout(1000.f, [&](){
    t.onTempPeriod(500.f, 1000.f, [](){std::cout << "a\n";});
});
```

Comment: Just guessing, the object was already destroyed? What does the breakpoint give you as context? What's the output by the debugger? Can you reduce the amount of code required to demonstrate the problem? Could you replace the tuple with a struct (which would also improve readability)?

Comment: Problems in HeapFree almost 100% of the time means you wrote before/after the ends of an array.

Comment: I should replace it, but this was made for a quick use before handing the project out. This is for separate project, and since I use Visual Studio 2012, I have to nest the tuples as well as you may have noticed. The thing is, the total output is: "Showoff.exe has triggered a breakpoint."(Showoff being the name of the project). I just tried in Release, and it works until I try to close the program. It pops the very same runtime error. It cant be destroyed, because it works for all other functions which do the very same thing, but dont nest call it(one `onPeriod` calls onTimeout successfully)